# Background logo not loading

Tags: html, css

It isn't displaying the picture I want to use as my own logo.

Here's a demo:

```css
body {
    background: rgb(211, 101, 101);
}
.logo{
    text-indent: -999999px;
    background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/250/333/fff/?text=Background%20Image');
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Comment: Use an image is more semantically correct.

Answer (score 3):

Try to give to the **logo** class a **width and height**.

> A background image is a background image, if there's no content, there is no width or height to display the image.

```
.logo{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   text-indent: -999999px;
   background: url('logo.png');
}
```

**See the demo..**

```css
body {
    background: rgb(211, 101, 101);
}
.logo{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   text-indent: -999999px;
   background: url('logo.png');
   background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/18mpK.png') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="logo"></div>
</body>
```